# Automatic updates dpkg packages

Tags: debian, deb

I have downloaded a Debian package over internet ( namely https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.13.0/atom-amd64.deb ).
After having installed it with

```
sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb
```

everything is fine. But a few weeks later, a new version comes out but I need to go through the same procedure as before. In my system, there are many deb packages in my computer that needs to be updated by hand.

Is there a way to make it automatically, like a bash script which makes it easier?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle updates is for the download site to provide a "package repository". There's isn't one for Atom, and Atom's documentation explicitly states

> The Linux version does not currently automatically update so you will need to repeat these steps to upgrade to future releases.

You can probably automate Atom downloads, by using the link to the [latest release](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/latest)...

Comment: Somebody could write a script that check the version number of the deb package and it automatically installs if it is greater than the previous number. I thought somebody might have written such as script. I think it is better to go website and install by hand.